# What is risk of moving pagefile.sys to another partition?

Tags: hard-drive, pagefile, risk

I have 4 physical drives 146 GB in my server (windows server 2008) configured as RAID 0 result of 2 logical drives C(50 GB) and drive D(remaining GB)

My system is showing alters of low disk space in C drive.
I tried to solve this problem, but unfortunately I have not found the perfect solution due to not availability of HD drives in market from type of my server (SunFire x4250).

The last solution is to remove unwanted files from drive C.
I empty the Temp folder, and also found pagefile.sys = 8 GB same as my RAM.

So is it safe and not affect performance to move this page file to drive D?

Please give me recommendations to make decision because I had read about that, and some of experts said it is safe to move to the other partition, but to other physically drive not to partition in the same drive. That confused me because I have physically 4 drive logically 2 drive letters as mentioned above.

Can you please help me to move this file? If not, what is the best solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can move this file to the different logical partition, but do not do it manually.
Instead:

1. Right Click Computer | Choose Properties
2. Click Advanced System Settings
3. Performance Tab | Click Settings
4. Advanced Settings Tab | Virtual Memory | Click Change
5. Uncheck Automaticaly manage page file
6. Clicking on disk will allow you to set paging file where you want

(https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/19d96eb1-669c-4605-8d63-7337f1c09084/how-to-relocate-pagefilesys-to-another-drive-letter?forum=winservergen)

You will need to reboot your server.

Comment: thanks @user996142 for you reply , what about stability of my OS, because if that leads to system crashes or low in performance that will be problem to our users,

Comment: If all drives in your RAID are healthy than it should not affect stability. Pagefile is for swap and system performance does not depend on it unless your server swaps heavily. And it should not do so, if you have enough RAM

Answer (score 4):

There is no risk in moving the pagefile to another disk, as long as that disk
can be depended upon to always be available.

The pagefile is usually not much used for swap if the RAM is sufficient for
the normal functioning of the computer. Its main use will in this case be to hold
the memory dump if the computer crashes inside the operating system.

Therefore the disk containing the pagefile does not need to be the fastest.
For example, if the system disk is an SSD, moving the pagefile to
a HDD will not impact negatively on performance.

In fact, moving the pagefile outside of the system disk can have the advantage
of reducing the size of eventual backups of the system and to speed them up.